# link two datepickers with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date

I have two datepickers one of them is for a start date and the other is for an end date. My problem is when i select a start date ,the end date datepicker should be after this date so that i should lock the other dates and if I select an end date input, the start date input should be after the end date.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="date_added">Date
                Courrier</label>
            <div class="input-group date">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                    class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input id="date_added"
                    type="text" class="form-control" value="03/04/2014">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-7" for="date_modified">Date
                Arrivée</label>
            <div class="input-group date">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                    class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input id="date_modified"
                    type="text" class="form-control" value="03/06/2014">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var start_date=$('#date_added').val();
    var end_date=$('#date_modified').val();


    $('#date_added').datepicker({

        onSelect: function(dateStr) {

            start_date=$(this).val();
            $('#date_modified').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(start_date));

        },
        todayBtn : "linked",
        keyboardNavigation : false,
        forceParse : false,
        calendarWeeks : true,
        autoclose : true
    });
    console.log("jjj")
    $('#date_modified').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateStr) {
            alert("Date is within two weeks");

            end_date=$(this).val();
            $('#date_added').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(end_date));

        },
        todayBtn : "linked",
        keyboardNavigation : false,
        forceParse : false,
        calendarWeeks : true,
        autoclose : true
    });

});


</script>
```

So what should I change

Comment: What is datepicker that you using?

Comment: this is a bootstrap based datepicker

Comment: you have to remove `onSelect` event inside the second datepicker because you dont want to update the first one depending on selected value on the second datepicker.. the rest of you code is fine , check this fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/ww18L033/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach the handlers of the [`changeDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate) event to the `#date_added` and `#date_modified` controls.

```js
var fromTimeInput = $('#date_added');
var toTimeInput = $('#date_modified');
var fromTime = fromTimeInput.val();
var toTime = toTimeInput.val();

fromTimeInput.datepicker({
    keyboardNavigation : false,
    forceParse : false,
    calendarWeeks : true,
    autoclose : true,
    endDate: toTime
});
toTimeInput.datepicker({
    keyboardNavigation : false,
    forceParse : false,
    calendarWeeks : true,
    autoclose : true,
    startDate: fromTime
});
fromTimeInput.on("changeDate", function (e) {
    toTimeInput.datepicker('setStartDate', e.date);
});
toTimeInput.on("changeDate", function (e) {
    fromTimeInput.datepicker('setEndDate', e.date);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="date_added">Date
                Courrier</label>
            <div class="input-group date">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                    class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input id="date_added"
                    type="text" class="form-control" value="03/04/2014">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-7" for="date_modified">Date
                Arrivée</label>
            <div class="input-group date">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                    class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input id="date_modified"
                    type="text" class="form-control" value="03/06/2014">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

To change displayed date format, day of the week start and other use [options](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#) of datepicker.

Comment: I'm very beginner on jQuery so can u show me how to integrate this code

Comment: I want that if for exemple `#date_added` is 16/05/2017 so `#date_modified` will be 16/05/2017 or after and if i select 16/05/2017 for `#date_modified` so `#date_added` will be 16/05/2017 or before

Comment: @WassimMakni , I create the interactive snippet for your. Try to run one. The date format is *month/day/year*.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var start_date=$('#date_added').val();
    var end_date=$('#date_modified').val();


    $('#date_added').datepicker({

        onSelect: function(dateStr) {

//Modification done here ;; 
           var dt = new Date(dateStr);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
            $("#date_modified").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);

        },
        todayBtn : "linked",
        keyboardNavigation : false,
        forceParse : false,
        calendarWeeks : true,
        autoclose : true
    });
    console.log("jjj")
    $('#date_modified').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateStr) {
            alert("Date is within two weeks");
        //Modification done here ;;
            var dt = new Date(dateStr);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
            $("#date_added").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);

        },
        todayBtn : "linked",
        keyboardNavigation : false,
        forceParse : false,
        calendarWeeks : true,
        autoclose : true
    });

});


</script>
```

Comment: My problem is that i can't access to the onSelect function even when i add a log inside the onSelect function it doesn't work

Comment: @wassim-makni can you please specify the error you are getting?

Comment: the inspect element on google chrome doesn't give me errors

Comment: If you can highlight where you are trying to put the log.

Comment: `$('#date_added').datepicker({

        onSelect: function(dateStr) {

console.log("jjj");///this doesn't work

            start_date=$(this).val();

            $('#date_modified').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(start_date));


        },`

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/f8e356) this is the result I am getting. Is this what is expected

Answer (score 0):

> here is solution - check snippet below

**jquery code:-**

```
$(function () {
            $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                onSelect: function (selected) {
                    var dt = new Date(selected);
                    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
                    $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
                }
            });
            $("#txtTo").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                onSelect: function (selected) {
                    var dt = new Date(selected);
                    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
                    $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
                }
            });
        });
```

```js
$(function () {
            $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                onSelect: function (selected) {
                    var dt = new Date(selected);
                    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
                    $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
                }
            });
            $("#txtTo").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                onSelect: function (selected) {
                    var dt = new Date(selected);
                    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
                    $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                From:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtFrom" />
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                To:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtTo" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```